# Funcion .init.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call();

Tags: javascript

Tengo una gran duda en un proyecto, no logro comprender el funcionamiento de estas líneas de código.

Es una función que se ejecuta al abrir la página web (`init`)
Pero no comprendo esas líneas exactamente ni por qué llevan esos parámetros

```
var __proveedores = (function() {
 return  {
        init: function() {
            __proveedores[urlActions[application.getAction()]].init.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call('init', 1));
        },
        mostrarAlerta: mostrarAlerta,
        showMessage: showMessage
    };
}
```

Lo que investigué es que `apply` sirve para utilizar métodos en diferentes objetos, pero a lo demas no logro entender su lógica

Answer (score 1):

quieres saber que es slice? como usarla? Yo uso slice cuando no quiero modificar mi Array original.

unos ejemplos de MDN:

```
    var animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

console.log(animals.slice(2));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck", "elephant"]

console.log(animals.slice(2, 4));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck"]

console.log(animals.slice(1, 5));
// expected output: Array ["bison", "camel", "duck", "elephant"]
```